# WebUsb API on Android

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, webusb

I'm developing a PWA that should communicate with a custom device by usb through an Android 9.0 tablet.

When I'm first trying to claim an interface the PWA cannot claim it because it's says that the interface is busy, If i try to use the usb device through a native app it works fine.
I tried to use the usb Device through the native app, when I disconnected the connection from the native app then I was able to claim the interface through the PWA.

- I found that it may not work because the android device auto claim the interface, can I do something directly from the PWA to claim the used interface?
- If not, will it work with the Serial API?
- I have some control over the device, maybe should I ask that it will implement another interface which I will be able to claim?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have used the WebUSB API just fine. But you are correct, you cannot have two or more clients claiming the USB device. 
I don't know anything about an auto claim for an application. Seems like a native app would abide by the same rules as a PWA and only be able to claim the USB device once the app is running.
The problem here is the API is poorly documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably running into is an Android kernel driver or another native application which has claimed the interface. In the WebUSB implementation on Android Chrome currently does not try to detach other drivers when claiming an interface. The issue below tracks considering whether it should.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1099521

If you can add an interface to the device which is not a standard USB interface class (for example, CDC or Printer) then you can avoid having the system automatically attach a driver to it.

Comment: I think the interface currently implemented is cdc-acm, and the native application on the tablet is implementing it. Because it implements it the kernel claims the interface even if the app isn't started at all?

Comment: I believe that the native application is requesting that the kernel release the interface. Chrome has the option of doing the same but doesn't take it. The issue I linked to tracks reconsidering whether it should.

Comment: Hi Reilly, Is there any update on the issue?