# WebUSB can not claim device on some android devices

Tags: webusb

I have a PWA using Web Serial on those devices where it is supported (Chromium based Desktop Browsers), on all other devices (basically Android) I try to fall back to Web USB via [web serial polyfill](https://github.com/google/web-serial-polyfill/issues).

This is working great for most devices, but on some (at leas one) Android devices I can not claim the device:

```
NetworkError: Unable to claim interface.
```

The interesting thing is that native apps can claim that device without issues.
The device in question is a Samsung Galaxy A5 running Android 8.

I checked `chrome://device-log/` everything is looking fine there:

```
[20:49:05] USB device added: id=1005 vendor=1155 "Betaflight", product=22336 "Betaflight STM32F411", serial="0x8000000", guid=9fa08f79-df5e-45bd-b757-c32ab1065bf9
[20:42:42] USB device removed: id=1004 guid=175af943-14ed-4591-a85b-b916a3a5584e
[20:40:42] USB device added: id=1004 vendor=1155 "Betaflight", product=22336 "Betaflight STM32F411", serial="0x8000000", guid=175af943-14ed-4591-a85b-b916a3a5584e
```

I then checked with this tool https://larsgk.github.io/webusb-tester/ and it confirms that there are two interfaces and neither of them is claimed:

```
2: Betaflight STM32F411 - VID: 0x0483, PID: 0x5740, S/N: 0x8000000
Interface 0 claimed: false
Interface 1 claimed: false
```

Unfortunately, or fortunately I could not find any other device where this is happening, but since it is happening on one device, it will happen on other devices.

I am not entirely sure what is happening, especially since native apps can claim the device.

The only related issue I could find id [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316858/webusb-api-on-android) - and from what I can see, there does not really seem to be a solution, if I understood correctly.

Is there any way to see what claims a device on Android?
Is there anything I can do to force claiming a device on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate of [that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316858/webusb-api-on-android) and automatically detaching drivers on Android (tracked by Chromium [issue 1099521](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1099521)) will resolve the problem.